# R mice: how to impute a correlation matrix

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice, psych

I am using the mice package on R to impute missing values for questionnaire, and and I want to find the polychoric correlation matrix so that I can do analysis on it (e.g. alpha, EFA).

I'm not sure how to specify this in the analysis step (`with()`).

Here is a min reproducible example using the `bfi` dataset from the `psych` package:

```r
library(psych)
library(tidyverse)
data <- bfi %>% 
  select(-c(gender, education, age))

# The analysis I want to do (demonstrating on original data set with missing data)
polychoric(data)$rho

# The imputation bit
imp <- mice(data)

# Trying to do the analysis on the imputed datasets
cor <- with(imp, ???) # Not sure how to put in the polychoric function here
```

Answer (score 0):

There's now a new function in `mice` (v3.16.0) to pool estimates of analyses that are not recognized by the `broom` workflow underlying the `pool()` function. See the `pool.table()` documentation on https://amices.org/mice/reference/pool.table

In your case, you would need to apply some further steps on the output of the `polychoric()` function to obtain the estimates that `mice` can pool.

```
# apply the polychric function to each imputed dataset
# then perform further analyses (e.g. fa())
compl <- mice::complete(imp, "all")
fits <- purrr::map(compl, ~{
  polychoric(.x)$rho # %>% 
  # ...
  # ...
  # ...
})

# combine estimates in the right format
# by filling in the NAs in the table below
ests <- data.frame(
  term = NA, 
  estimate = NA, 
  std.error = NA, 
  df.residual = NA)

# apply pool.table() function
mice::pool.table(ests)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cor <- with(imp, polychoric(data)$rho)
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.